# Separate column with extracted years

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to select employees whose work experience is currently more or equal to 15 years. Also I have to display their work experience in years in a separate column.

I have tried this

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "Fn and Ln" 
 FROM HR.EMPLOYEES WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), HIRE_DATE)), '%Y') 
 + 0 >= 15;
```

I'm stuck on "ORA-00904: "DATE_FORMAT": invalid identifier" and also I don't know how to create a separate column with their work experience (in years).

Database:

[image: DB]

Comment: Use `MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hire_date) >= 15 * 12`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is

```
where extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from hire_date) >= 15
```

If table isn't too large, performance won't suffer because of possible index on `hire_date` column. If it does, say so.

Comment: This is wrong as `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '2022-11-04') - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '2007-12-31')` will return 15 but there is less that 15 years between the two dates.

Comment: If you're interested in years only, then it is OK, @MT0. If you're interested in months and days as well, then it is wrong.  It depends.